# Ошибки при подклчении библиотек в GoLang

Tags: golang

Пишу маленькую программу и понадобились библиотеки с гитхаба, когда скачал и подключил в консоль выдает следующее:

/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/gorequest.go:32:2: cannot find package "github.com/moul/http2curl" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/vendor/github.com/moul/http2curl (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/moul/http2curl (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/src/github.com/moul/http2curl (from $GOPATH)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/curl-to-go-gh-pages/src/github.com/moul/http2curl
    /usr/local/go/pkg/errors/src/github.com/moul/http2curl
    /home/deer/GoLand-173.3727.96/src/github.com/moul/http2curl
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/gorequest.go:22:2: cannot find package "github.com/pkg/errors" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/vendor/github.com/pkg/errors (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/pkg/errors (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/src/github.com/pkg/errors (from $GOPATH)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/curl-to-go-gh-pages/src/github.com/pkg/errors
    /usr/local/go/pkg/errors/src/github.com/pkg/errors
    /home/deer/GoLand-173.3727.96/src/github.com/pkg/errors
/usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/gorequest.go:33:2: cannot find package "golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/vendor/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix (vendor tree)
    /usr/local/go/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix (from $GOROOT)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/gorequest-develop/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix (from $GOPATH)
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/curl-to-go-gh-pages/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix
    /usr/local/go/pkg/errors/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix
    /home/deer/GoLand-173.3727.96/src/golang.org/x/net/publicsuffix

Process finished with exit code 1

Подскажите пожалуйста как исправить.

Answer (score 1):

Он не может найти пакеты. Убедитесь, что  у вас `GOPATH` правильно установлен и не совпадает с `GOROOT`. Если он установлен правильно, то выполните `go get -d ./...` в папке проекта для загрузки всех зависимостей.

Answer (score 0):

У вас не настроен GOPATH и/или не совпадает GOROOT.
Если вы используете компилятор который не устанавлен в PATH то одним из решений будет возможность поправить содержимое `~/.bashrc` в своей домашней директории.

Ниже пример из моего `.bashrc`:

```
# Компилятор скачан с сайта и распакован в ~/.local/go1.9.2
export GOROOT=$HOME/.local/go1.9.2

# Директория с зависимостями в ~/go_libs
export GOPATH=$HOME/go_libs

# Добавляем записи в PATH
export PATH=$GOROOT/bin:$GOPATH/bin
```

После изменения `.bashrc` перезапустите терминал, или выполните `source ~/.bashrc`.

[Структура проекта](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

[Хорошая статья о различиях GOPATH и GOROOT](https://habrahabr.ru/post/249545/)